# file data not showing in html page

Tags: django

my task is to show folder data in html page . but its showing blank page please any one help me where  iam doing mistake.

view.py

```
def info(request,id):
    INFO_DIR = '/home/des-0064/Logs'
    req_path = os.path.join(INFO_DIR, id)
    file_content = dict()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(req_path):
        for file_name in files:
            full_path =  os.path.join(root,file_name)
            with open(full_path, 'r') as _file:
                #file_content[file_name] = _file.read()
                file_content[file_name] = _file.read()
    print file_content

    for file_name, content in file_content.iteritems():
        print file_name
        print content

    return HttpResponse (request, 'info.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just prints to the console, you need to pass this through to your template in a context variable.

At the very least you can pass through the content after creating json out of it.

```
return HttpResponse(request,
                    'info.html',
                    {'file_contents': json.dumps(file_content.iteritems())})
```

You can then use the `file_contents` in your template

<sub>I'm assuming that you can actually see the contents printed on your console and that code all works</sub>

Comment: @annonymus - Updated, you need to jsonify it first

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the file_content to the html template.

```
return HttpResponse(request, 'info.html', file_contents)
```

Passing it as above will allow you to iterate over all the files and display their content. You template code would be something like this.

```
{% for file, content in file_contents %}
    Name: {{ file }}
    Content: {{ content }}
{% endfor %}
```